# Jackson2HashMapper not serializing Date with Flatten=True

Tags: redis, spring-data, jackson2

Using the Jackson Hash Mapper with Flatten=true my Date fields are getting discarded. Is this the correct behaviour or a bug? Is there a way to have Date serialized with Flatten=true?

I've used the following test Pojo:

```
import java.util.Date;
public class FooClass{
  private Boolean foolean;
  private Integer barteger;
  private String simpleString;
  private Date myDate;
  public void setFoolean(Boolean value){ foolean = value; }
  public Boolean getFoolean(){ return foolean; }
  public void setBarteger(Integer value){ barteger = value; }
  public Integer getBarteger(){ return barteger; }
  public void setSimpleString(String value) { simpleString = value; }
  public String getSimpleString(){ return simpleString; }
  public void setMyDate(Date value) { myDate = value; }
  public Date getMyDate(){ return myDate; }
}

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, 
    JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    Jackson2HashMapper hashMapper = new Jackson2HashMapper(true);

    FooClass fooObject = new FooClass();
    fooObject.setFoolean(true);
    fooObject.setBarteger(10);
    fooObject.setSimpleString("Foobar");
    fooObject.setMyDate(new Date());

    Map<String, Object> hash = hashMapper.toHash(fooObject);
    for (String key: hash.keySet())
    {
      System.out.println("hash contains: " + key + "=" + 
      hash.get(key.toString()));
    }

    FooClass newFoo = (FooClass)(hashMapper.fromHash(hash));
    System.out.println("FromHash: " + newFoo);
  }
}
```

In this case I get the following output:

```
hash contains: @class=FooClass
hash contains: foolean=true
hash contains: barteger=10
hash contains: simpleString=Foobar
FromHash: FooClass@117159c0
```

If I change new Jackson2HashMapper(false); then I get:

```
hash contains: @class=FooClass
hash contains: foolean=true
hash contains: barteger=10
hash contains: simpleString=Foobar
hash contains: myDate=[java.util.Date, 1547033077869]
FromHash: FooClass@7ed7259e
```

I was expecting to get the Date field serialized in both cases - perhaps with an additional field describing the date type (flattened).

I traced the reason for this to the following line in the HashMapper code:
`typingMapper.enableDefaultTyping(DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, As.PROPERTY);`
Where the mapper is configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to issue in `Jackson2HashMapper`.
After digging into the source of Jackson2HashMapper, it seems to issue in `Jackson2HashMapper`.
created an issue for this, [DATAREDIS-1001
Jackson2HashMapper does not serialize Date/Calender fields when flatten = true](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-1001)

Comment: They have fixed the issue ... will be part of next snapshot